# DNS resolution works most of the time but randomly fails. Usually on Google Chrome. Seems to be specific to computers at my house

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns, azure, linux-on-azure

I recently built a website and attached it to a domain name. I bought the domain name from Google domains and added an A record pointing the domain to the IP address of the server I'm running it on. This server is an Ubuntu Server VM on Azure. Whenever I try to access the website from outside of my home WiFi it loads.

- When I try to access it from inside my home WiFi, it works some of the time and fails at other times.
- It always works within my home WiFi when I type in the IP address of the server. In fact, I have the server configured to do a 301 redirect to the https port, and this always executes flawlessly. When this happens, the final address in my browser reads https://based-it.com, which is what I want.
- When I type https://based-it.com explicitly, it fails about half the time. Sometimes I get a DNS lookup error from chrome, sometimes I get a "Page Failed to Load" error.
- Running nslookup on my local machine from within my home WiFi always returns the correct IP address, although it always says it's "non-authoritative". I'm using the built-in DNS service provided by Google, which I assume should work.

It's been about 27 hours since I added the A record. I would assume that by now it should be working. I am particularly concerned because the only network that appears to be having trouble is my own. I have tried configuring Google chrome to use my ISP DNS server. When I do this, it redirects me to some Verizon search engine page. When I configure chrome to use the google DNS servers, it usually just gives me a DNS lookup error. As I mentioned above, sometimes that isn't the error.

I've monitored the webserver live through ssh while these errors occur. It clearly isn't even receiving a connection when I get the "Page Failed to Load" error. Something outside of my control appears to be failing.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily a general purpose answer, *but*, the issue resolved itself after a few days. It's important for me to note that I also went and added a *www* record. This seemed to fix the issue for the most part. I'm not sure if it was time, or that record that fixed it.

I should note that I still *occasionally* get DNS lookup failures, but they are much less frequent. They still only happen inside my home WiFi network.